# How to implement an efficient incremental search in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to determine the largest interval `y[i0:i1] > y_val` by incrementally searching from a start index `i_start` in a Numpy array `y`. I am only interested in the largest interval around `i_start`. A sample implementation looks like this:

```
from typing import Optional, Tuple

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def arg_lt_interval(x: np.ndarray, idx_start: int, val: float) \
        -> Tuple[Optional[int], Optional[int]]:
    """Search `idx0, idx1` where `x[idx0:idx1] >= val`
    starting at `x[idx_start]`. """
    if x[idx_start] < val:
        return None, None

    idx0, idx1 = idx_start, idx_start + 1

    for i in range(idx_start+1, len(x)):
        if x[i] < val:
            idx1 = i
            break

    for i in range(idx_start-1, 0, -1):
        if x[i] < val:
            idx0 = i + 1
            break

    return idx0, idx1



# Test the function arg_lt_interval():
t = np.linspace(0, np.pi*1.5, 30)
y = abs(np.sin(t))
i_start, y_val = 10, 0.4

i0, i1 = arg_lt_interval(y, i_start, y_val)

fg1, ax1 = plt.subplots(num=1, clear=True)
ax1.set(title=f"Mark all values y[i] > {y_val=}, starting at {i_start=}",
        xlabel="$i$", ylabel="$y[i]$")
ax1.plot(y, 'C0.-', label=r"$y[i]$")
ax1.plot(i_start, y[i_start], 'C1o', label=f"y[{i_start=}]" )
ax1.fill_between(np.arange(i0, i1), y[i0:i1], color='C2', alpha=.5,
                 label="$y[i] > y_{val}$")
ax1.axhline(y_val, color='C4', label=f"{y_val=}")
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.legend()
plt.show()
```

The green area in the plot marks the `y[3:17]`, which is the desired interval. The interval `y[22:]` should be ignored:
[image: Figure 1]

Since there are two `for` loops in `arg_lt_interval()`, this implementation is not very fast. Is there a way by utilizing Numpy functions to make it faster?
Thanks.

Comment: Iterating on a list is faster than iterating on an array.  I don't know if that's relevant here or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in both directions starting from i_start

```
def get_interval(y,i_start,val):
    left_index = (i_start - np.argmax(y[:i_start][::-1] < val)) 
    right_index = np.argmax(y[i_start:] < val) + i_start
    return ( left_index,right_index)
```

Comment: Rather accepting the answer late than never. Rereading it makes sense now.